# Can arbirary configuration for tests be set in pytest.ini?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to centralize configuration for my tests and it seems like pytest.ini would be the place but I'm having trouble finding an example/feature for this.

For example I have a directory with files my tests might need called "test_resources". this is my structure:

```
├── pytest.ini
├── myproject
│    └── someFunctionsOne
│        ├── one.py
│        └── two.py
└── tests
    ├── integration
    │   └── someFunctionsOneTestblah.py
    ├── test_resources
    │   ├── sample-data.json
    │   └── test-data-blahablahb.csv
    └── unit
        └── someFunctionsOne
            ├── one.py
            └── two.py
```

I want to set the path of "test_resources" in `pytest.ini`. So integration and unit tests know where to find that folder- I'd like to avoid hard coding paths like this in my test files themselves.

Is there a feature to set arbitrary config in `pytest.ini` and retrieve it from tests? I suspect I might have other config settings like this for my tests and if all that lives in the `pytest.ini` file that makes things much clearer for other devs on this project- one place to go for all test configuration stuff. I already have a configuration file for my *application* which is loaded when it starts but that's different. I want to isolate the unit/integration test config from my application config. `pytest.ini` seems like the best place because it's already there and used by the tests. This way I don't need to create another config file and roll my own mechanism for loading it for the tests

Also, I know there is nothing preventing me from using configparser or even loading and parsing `pytest.ini` myself but if tests are already using it I was hoping there would be a built-in feature to read arbitrary kvs from it or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define custom keys in `pytest.ini` same way as you define custom command line arguments, only using the [`Parser.addini`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.config.argparsing.Parser.addini) method:

```
# conftest.py

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addini("mykey", help="help for my key", default="fizz")
```

(Note that `pytest_addoption` hook impls should be located in the top-level `conftest.py`).

You now can define `mykey` in `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
mykey = buzz
```

Access `mykey` value in tests:

```
def test_spam(request):
    value = request.config.getini("mykey")
    assert value == "buzz"
```

Comment: conftest.py should go at the root of the project where pytest.ini is  located right? Also, a little confused about what `request` is. Is that like self? Im not using classes in my tests will that still work?

Comment: _conftest.py should go at the root of the project where pytest.ini is located right?_ Yes, best is to put it in the project root dir, or in a tests root dir if you have one. _Also, a little confused about what `request` is._ [It's a regular fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html), it's used if you want to access test internals (config, session, test case object etc). _Im not using classes in my tests will that still work?_ Sure.

Comment: So "request" doesnt need to be defined somewhere as a `@pytest.fixture`  first? I can just use "empty" fixtures like this? Sorry, somewhat outside scope of question just want to understand this part

Comment: No worries! `request` is part of predefined fixtures that is implemented by `pytest` itself. You can use any of the fixtures in the doc I linked to above, they are all implemented and loaded automatically when your test execution starts. Other fixtures may be provided by plugins if you have installed any. Run `pytest --fixtures` to list all fixtures available in your local setup.