# Can conftest.py _read_ an existing value from pytest.ini?

Tags: python, pytest

conftest.py can be used to define properties in pytest.ini with `parser.addini()` but can conftest.py also read existing values from pytest.ini?

I would like to look at the value of a parameter in pytest.ini and use it to set the default value of another parameter in pytest.ini

Is this possible without having to use configparser myself in conftest.py?

Comment: By using `config.getini("key")`? I gave you an example in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61433042/2650249) yesterday.

Comment: i can use config.getini("key") from _inside_ conftest itself? I haven't seen any examples of that

Comment: You can't read ini values on module top-level, if that's what you mean. But it shouldn't be necessary anyway; what's your use case?

Comment: I would like to look at the value of a parameter in pytest.ini and use it to set the default value of another parameter in pytest.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to look at the value of a parameter in pytest.ini and use it to set the default value of another parameter in pytest.ini

Best is to add a custom impl of the `pytest_configure` hook. Example: assume you have two custom ini options defined in your `conftest.py`:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addini("fizz", help="help for my key", default="buzz")
    parser.addini("spam", help="help for my key", default="eggs")
```

Now `spam` should be set to `bacon` whenever `fizz` is not `buzz` (not the default value). Extend `conftest.py` with:

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    fizz = config.getini("fizz")
    spam = config.getini("spam")
    print("values parsed from ini: fizz:", fizz, "spam:", spam)

    if not fizz == "buzz":
        # override parsed ini value
        config._inicache["spam"] = "bacon"

    print("spam was replaced to:", config.getini("spam"))
```

When running `pytest -s` (and `fizz` set to something else than `buzz` in `pytest.ini`), you will get the following output:

```
values parsed from ini: fizz: fuzz spam: eggs
spam was replaced to: bacon
============================= test session starts =============================
...
```

Comment: thats awesome! so glad I dont have to parse it myself inside conftest!

Comment: Glad I could help!